# Need examples of impressive Silverlight (4) applications

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, .net-4.0

What are some examples of impressive Silverlight (preferably 4) applications?

To explain what I mean, I mean *real applications* that aren't just some single-function, tool apps (unless it's a game or simulator). And *please exclude* apps whose primary purpose is to stream media (i.e. Netflix, NBC Beijing Olympics).

What are some open-source, demo, or real-world Silverlight apps that push the capabilities of .NET 4 to the fullest; that really showcase what Silverlight is capable of? It would be great if these Silverlight apps take advantage of .NET 4 *outside* of the [System.Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms599716%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) namespace as well. Does anyone make innovative use of, for example, [WCF Data Services for Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838234%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)? How about a noteworthy implementation of the MVVM pattern?

What are some examples that had you thinking "how did they do that?", or you just thought were interesting? The UI doesn't necessarily have to be impressive; maybe it was just an elegant solution to a complex real-world problem, only it was implemented with Silverlight.

(I already looked at the [showcase](http://www.silverlight.net/showcase/), thank you very much.)

Answer (score 1):

Working mainly on health care applications, I was really impress by this [Microsoft demo](http://www.mscui.net/)

Answer (score 1):

[Hard Rock Memorabilia](http://memorabilia.hardrock.com/)

[Classroom](http://www.tutor.com/Classroom/Classroom.aspx?Practice=1)

[Mazda Configuration](http://www.mazda.de/konfigurator/konfiguratorsl.aspx)

[Game](http://www.joerassic.ch/)

[World wide Telescope](http://www.worldwidetelescope.org/webclient/)

Answer (score 1):

Check out fdeck: http://www.telerik.com/products/fdeck.aspx. It was originally developed by Microsoft for PDC09 as their crowd-pleaser for Silverlight 4.0 - I guess they handed it off to Telerik at the 2010 Silverlight Firestarter event.

Comment: it looks like it must be installed. is there any URL that has this app running from the browser only?